# Website gone from google with any worpdress Seo Plugin

Tags: wordpress, seo

I have a problem with Seo plug-in when i active a plugin in my website it's look fine but after a 3 days the site gone from Google search.
I have tried with another plugin and the same things.
If i disabled the seo plug-in like now, the website comeback to google search.

I tried All in one Seo pack , and Yaost Seo.

Any suggestion ?

http://papillonvoyages.ma/

Answer (score 0):

Robotos File look like this

> User-agent: *
>
> Disallow: /wp-admin/
>
> Sitemap: http://papillonvoyages.ma/sitemap.xml

Comment: Any help for this problem ?